# WP_Query get posts from custom posts by category

Tags: posts, wp-query

ive been playing around with this for ages and for some reason I cant get it to work.

This is from within the single post page of a custom post type...

Basically I am getting the category of the custom post type by using the get_the_term and then doing a foreach to nicely input into a string.

I then use a WP_Query to retrieve, but I think I have the logic wrong.

This is what I have

```
// post types query
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :the_post();

// getting the categories
$categorynames = '';
$getcategory = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'custompostnamehere-categories');

foreach($getcategory as $t){ $categorynames .= $t->term_id.' ,';}

if (substr($categorynames, -1) == ',') {
$categorynames = substr($categorynames, 0, -1);
}

// end of post type query
endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); 

//starting new query to get related posts within the same categories
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'custompostnamehere',
  'cat' => $categorynames,
  'posts_per_page' => 20
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);

// retrieving the data
while($q->have_posts()){

}
```

Could someone please enlighten me on my wrong doings.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're using category query for your custom taxonomy. So it won't work, because there are no categories with such IDs.

You should use tax_query instead.

```
// post types query
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    // getting the categories
    $categoryIDs = array();  // it's much nicer than concatenated string
    $getcategory = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'custompostnamehere-categories');

    foreach($getcategory as $t) {
        $categoryIDs[] = $t->term_id;
    }

// end of post type query
}
// resetting query isn't needed - you will call your own query next

//starting new query to get related posts within the same categories
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custompostnamehere',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'yourcustomtaxonomy',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $categoryIDs
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 20
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);

// retrieving the data
while( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help and logically I can see this, but its running an infinite loop :(

Comment: Did you put `$q->the_post()` in second loop?

Comment: No, its exactly what you have done. :(

Comment: I just modified your code, where there were errors. Rest is just copied. Every time you use `have_posts()` in loop, you should call `the_post()` in that loop or you'll get infinite loop.

Comment: `$categoryIDs = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'custompostnamehere-categories', array('fields' => 'ids') );` avoid the foreach loop

Comment: @G.M. There is nothing wrong with foreach (look at `wp_get_object_terms` implementation). So there's no need to complicate the solution (I was trying to make as little modifications as I could, to get this working). Is it perfect? Of course it's not.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż never said foreach loop is _wrong_, but IMHO foreach loop is a more complicate solution: you declare array, call get_the_terms, perform foreach loop. `wp_get_object_terms` do the _same_ (not better, nor worse) using one line of code still keeping (improving?) the readability. Again, it's an opinion.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly like you say. `wp_get_object_terms` is nicer way to do this (and yes, I agree that you shoud use it here - mainly for compatibility reasons), but it is also more complex (just look at it's implementation - it does much more than this one loop does).